# Convert CVSNT to SVN

Tags: svn, cvs

Is there any reliable way to convert CVSNT to SVN?

Comment: Is cvs2svn not working for you? http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html

Comment: There is a remark "cvs2svn does not support conversion of CVSNT repositories. Some people have indicated success with such conversions, while others have had problems. In other words, such conversions, even if apparently successful, should be checked carefully before use". I wanted to know alternatives before starting converting with cvs2svn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `cvs2svn` is not reliable in this case, as the [CVS FAQ mentions](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#cvsnt):

> **[CVSNT](http://www.cvsnt.org/)** is a version control system that started out by adding support for running CVS under Windows NT. Since then it has made numerous extensions to the RCS file format, to the point where CVS compatibility does not imply CVSNT compatibility with any degree of certainty.
>
> `cvs2svn` might happen to successfully convert a CVSNT repository, especially if the repository has never had any CVSNT-only features used on it, but this use is not supported and should not be expected to work.
>
> If you want to experiment with converting a CVSNT repository, then please consider the following suggestions:
>
> - Use cvs2svn's **`--use-cvs`** option.
> - Use CVSNT's version of the cvs executable (i.e., ensure that the first cvs program in your `$PATH` is the one that came with CVSNT).
> - Carefully check the result of the conversion before you rely on it, even if the conversion completed without any errors or warnings.

---

That being said, try first with the `--use-cvs` option: it has [been reported to work](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.cvs2svn.user/2410) (even though you still need to carefully check the result).